# HttpDelete not working in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webdav, http-delete

I am trying to create `HttpDelete`service in my `Web Api` but its not working and giving me the follwoing error

```
Handler "WebDAV" has a bad module "WebDAVModule" in its module list
```

My service code implemented as follows

```
   [HttpDelete]
    public string DeleteItem(long itemId)
    {
        try
        {
            // Implementation goes here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I am using the following http request using `Postman` plugin using `HTTPDelete` method

```
  http://localhost:85/RM.Services/api/Item/DeleteItem?itemId=12
```

I used the following configuration to solve this issue at `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

also trying the following settings in `web.config`

```
  <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

but nothing work for me the same error appears

I tried to remove `WebDav` from `IIS` with the following steps

1. go to `Control Panel` then `Programs and Fetures` then `Turn windows features on or off`
2. then `Internet Information Services` then `World Wide Web Services` then `Common HTTP Features`
3. then remove `WebDav Features`

In this case i recieved `404` error

Any help in this issue?

Comment: Post your action method code please

Comment: check edited question

Comment: please add code where you are calling this action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i removed the following configuration from `Web.config`

```
<modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>`
```

and keep

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
</handlers>
```

and now everything is working fine

Answer (score 1):

In `Web API` you shouldn't put action DeleteItem in your URL, here the routing is different from `MVC`. You should call using `HTTPDelete` method and use this url:

```
http://localhost:85/RM.Services/api/Item/12
```

Comment: what if i have two action services both marked with `HTTPDelete` what is the url will be?

Comment: the best matching by parameters

Comment: ok i tried this but still not working the same error appears `Handler "WebDAV" has a bad module "WebDAVModule" in its module list`

Comment: even if you delete it from web.config?

Comment: yes i removed the configration added to `web.config` realted to `WebDav`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116087/discussion-between-mohamed-salah-and-roma).